# why the agent is blocked for my code?

Tags: clojure

**description:**
i have a list(named large-number-list) which contains many number in it,and i want get the sum of these number.
now i divide the list into three element as one group to calculate(this group will be calculated in a action of agent),  and put the sum of these three element into a vector(named result).
at last,i accumulate the element in the vector together.

**code as following:**

```
;use agent to calculate many number  
(def result (agent []))  
(def large-number-list [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]);assume that large-number-list contains many number in it   
(defn doin3 [col do-fn]  
    (let [[x1 x2 x3 & rest-elem]  col  
         rest-len (count rest-elem)]  
         (println "x1 x2 x3" x1 x2 x3)  
         (println "rest-len is " rest-len)  
         (do-fn x1 x2 x3)  
         (when (> rest-len 0) (doin3 rest-elem do-fn))))  
;assume that the calculate is a time-consumed operation  
(defn calculate [v x1 x2 x3]   
    (conj v (+ x1 x2 x3)))  
(doin3 large-number-list #(send result calculate %1 %2 %3))  
(println "before await")  
(await result)  
(println "after await")  
(println @result)  
(def total (apply + result))  
(println "total is:" total)  
(shutdown-agents)
```

**expected output:**

```
x1 x2 x3 1 2 3  
rest-len is  9  
x1 x2 x3 4 5 6  
rest-len is  6  
x1 x2 x3 7 8 9  
rest-len is  3  
x1 x2 x3 10 11 12  
rest-len is  0  
before await  
after await  
total is: 78
```

**actual output:**

```
x1 x2 x3 1 2 3  
rest-len is  9  
x1 x2 x3 4 5 6  
rest-len is  6  
x1 x2 x3 7 8 9  
rest-len is  3  
x1 x2 x3 10 11 12  
rest-len is  0  
before await
```

**question:**
the code run to "before await" and block,i guess that the action in agent is not finished,but why?
please let me know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you doing this to learn about agents or do you actually want to compute this? Because there are better ways to do that, which don't involve agents (or state for that matter).

Comment: Each `send` to the agent is enqueuing an action on the agent's (single) thread. If you `send` a large number of actions to that agent then ask to `await` that agent, then you will have to wait until the queue has been processed. You are not doing these actions in parallel as you may have thought.

Comment: @ivant  @A. Webb  you are right.the best way is that:  `(println (reduce + 0 (pmap #(reduce + 0 %) (partition 3 3 [0] large-number-list))))`

Comment: @mingw See [reducers/fold](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
(def total (apply + result))
```

It should be:

```
(def total (apply + @result))
```

It wasn't actually blocking, it was throwing an exception.

One more note: you should consider using `recur` in `doin3`, instead of direct call, as it's in a tail position already.